# Examining file structure in application jar

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I have a directory in my jar called "lessons".  Inside this directory there are x number of lesson text files.  I want to loop through all these lessons read their data.

I of course know how to read a file with an exact path:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("lessons/lesson1.lsn")));
    try{
        in.readLine();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But what I want is something more like this:

```
File f = new File(Main.class.getResource("lessons"));
    String fnames[] = f.list();
    for(String fname : fnames){
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("lessons/" + fname)));
        in.readLine();
    }
```

File however doesn't take a URL in it's constructor, so that code doesn't work.

Comment: A Jar file is just a Zip file.  You will need to read it as such.  This will allow you to determine the names of the files contained with and you can continue using the `getResource` method for each named resource

Answer (score 0):

I will use junit.jar in my test as an example

String url = Test1.class.getResource("/org/junit").toString();

produces

```
jar:file:/D:/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar!/org/junit
```

lets extract jar path

```
String path = url.replaceAll("jar:file:/(.*)!.*", "$1");
```

it is

```
D:/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
```

now we can open it as JarFile and read it

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(path);
...
```